Distribution of SMAP L4 product delay
According to the NSIDC webpage, there is an average delay of SMAP L4 images of 2 days and 16 hours. I am however more interested in the distribution of this delay.
When looking through images in the SPL4SMGP collection both through google earth engine and NASA Earthdata, there is indeed information about when an image was posted, which I can compare to the time the image was captured to get my result, but this information gets overwritten whenever they update the image. So I am at a loss. Does anyone know from experience, or have an idea of how to find out?
